# Spring-MVC 406 Not Acceptable instead of JSON Response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to return a JSON response with Spring 3.0.6, but I get a 406 response "Not Acceptable", with the description: 
"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics 
not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ()."

I know that [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069903/spring-mvc-not-returning-json-content-error-4069903) has been asked before, but I can't make it work for my project, despite many 
tests and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

In my Maven pom.xml I've the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

In web.xml I reference webmvc-config.xml, and the log confirms that is loaded.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In webmvc-config.xml I've the following:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class ClassifiedController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/classified/{idClassified}", headers = "Accept=*/*",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final Classified getClassified(@PathVariable final int idClassified) {
        ...
```

I tried with or without the headers parameter with the same results. If I call the URL
directly with Firefox the Request Headers contain the following (checked with firebug):

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

If I use the following JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/classified/38001',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
});
```

The following headers are sent:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

In both cases the result is a 406 error. I don't know what else should I check to make
it work.

---

**UPDATE**: I decided to debug through Spring and I found out that Jackson was called correctly and in org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider the method _findExplicitUntypedSerializer contains the following code:

```
try {
    return _createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(runtimeType, property);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

This is unfortunate because hides the source of the problem. With the debugger I found out that that exception contained a very descriptive error message:

```
Conflicting getter definitions for property "reminded": 
ClassifiedImpl#isReminded(0 params) vs
ClassifiedImpl#getReminded(0 params)
```

Now that I see the error message is a silly mistake and easy to fix, but without that it wasn't that obvious. In fact, fixing the problem, leaded to a working serialization.

Comment: did you check encoding of output / i think their is some limit in json heder content

Comment: Is `Accept` correct for the `@RequestMapping` annotation? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced - might suggest "`content-type`".

Comment: Do you have another AnnotationHandlerMapping bean created in your context?

Comment: @nidhin, do you mean in the Request Headers? I've this:
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Comment: @Paul Grime, I think both are acceptable, anyway I tried with headers = "content-type=*/*" and now I've a 404.

Comment: Maybe have to debug your way through Spring. Or check your JSPs as this sounds like Spring found a controller to handle the request, but can't find a view? What view name does your Controller return?

Comment: @Paul Grime, I don't return any view name, since I've the ResponseBody annotation, I return a JavaBean that should be shown as JSON, and it didn't work. Your comment inspired me to try with a Map instead and that works! Thank you. I'm not sure why. Is MappingJacksonJson working only with Maps and not JavaBeans?

Comment: Does the class follow regular JavaBean conventions with getter / setters, default constructor etc.. JacksonJsonConverter works with Java Beans.

Comment: @gkamal: yes with the caveat that Classified is an interface. I tried also returning ClassifiedImpl directly, but it still gives 406. The implementation has a public default constructor, plus public getters and setters and a few other methods too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of the [MappingJacksonJson](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html) processing, you'll need to make sure that the [Jackson ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) supports [your object type](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#canSerialize%28java.lang.Class%29) for serialisation.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the help, what you say makes sense. However, I tried to add the Serializable interface to my Classified interface: "public interface Classified extends Serializable" and I still have 406, in both cases: returning the interface or the concrete implementation.

Comment: This isn't java.io Serialization. A Jackson Serializer needs to be registered with Jackson. Read the docs for ObjectMapper and http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializerProvider.html.

Comment: Dude , you're a savior . Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following in DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml.

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've stumbled upon the same error (406: content not acceptable) with Spring MVC and  @RestController annotation.

**The Spring handler:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff-acknowledgment/{id}", produces ="application/json;charset=UTF-8", headers="Accept=*")
public Message acknowledgeStuff(@PathVariable("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("ack") AckBean acquittement) {
```

**Observation:**

- the URI has the form : `http://www.host.com/stuff-acknowledgment/{id}`
- BUT `$id` has a very particular format: `xxxcomplicatedhashxxx.png` (or whatever extension you can think of).

**Therefore:**

Spring MVC interpret the extension and want to produce a result of that same mime type (even if I define it as a path variable), here an `"image/png"` MIME type even if I tell him to produce JSON. So a 406 exception is thrown.

**Fix:**

Remove the `".png"` extension in the URI, or remove the PathVariable and put it in the body, or add a suffix behind the pathVariable (not tested but should work as well), the point is to avoid a file extension at the end of the URI.

P.S.: I know it doesn't answer the specific problem (with the solution in the update) in the question but I found that SO thread when searching for that problem and post my fix here for the record, hoping it can help someone in the future.

Comment: Same thing here,  the endpoint had an email address at the very end  which lead to interpreting  TLD  extension  like so    value=someServer/{folder}/{email} . I swapped the arguments and all was working fine .I wish i can up vote more for this answer, thanks agin :)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem because the objects that I wanted to return as JSON didn't have any getter methods for their properties. Jackson probably needs these. After adding them it worked.

Answer (score 2):

although this thread is a little old...

u need to add the following (maven dependency):

org.codehaus.jacksonjackson-mapper-asl1.9.13