# 406 Not Acceptable Spring MVC JSON

Tags: json, jquery, spring-mvc

When I send AJAX Post request on server with JSON 
In firebug POST 406 Not Acceptable

```
Response headers
Content-Length  1067
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 02 Dec 2013 11:45:09 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request headers
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Content-Length  296
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  id=8; JSESSIONID=61E68D2A0464C2E5B82F59F921EE598C
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
X-Requested-With    
XMLHttpRequest
```

The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcomment.html", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,headers="Content-Type=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody MyComment AddComment(@RequestBody MyComment comm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        MyComment myComment = new MyComment();
        String idArticle2 = String.valueOf(comm.getArticleId().getArticleId());
        String comment = comm.getComment();
        String idUser = String.valueOf(comm.getAuthorId().getUserId());


        MyArticle art = new MyArticle();
        art.setArticleId(Integer.parseInt(idArticle2));

        MyUser user = new MyUser();
        user.setUserId(Integer.parseInt(idUser));

        myComment.setParrentId(0);
        myComment.setArticleId(art);
        myComment.setComment(comment);
        myComment.setAuthorId(user);
        myComment.setMyDate(new Date());


        myCommentServ.addComment(myComment);

        return myComment;
}
```

ajax post request

```
$('#addcomment').click(function(){
    var idUser = $("#idUser").data("idd");
    var idArticle = $('#idArticle').val();
    var myComment = $('#myComment').val();

   var dataaa = {"id":null,"comment":myComment,"id_author":{"id":idUser,"login":null,"password":null,"email":null,"photo":null},"id_article":{"id":idArticle, "title":null, "description":null,"article":null,"mydate":null,"id_author":null}, "id_parent":0,"mydate":null};
   $.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8088/MyBlog.ua/addcomment.html",
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: dataaa,
contentType: 'application/json',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
        },
success: function(data) {
    alert("OK");
},
error:function(data,status,er) {
    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
}
});
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
<context:component-scan base-package="newpackage" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

 <error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>MyBlog</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MyBlog</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
<id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
<name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
<url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
<name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
<url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring 3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jackson -->

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.13</version>
     </dependency> 
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>20030825.184428</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
  <version>20030825.183949</version>
</dependency>

<!-- junit,selenium-->
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>  
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>  
    <version>1.9.5</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.37.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.37.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.37.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I send json on server I get 406 Not Acceptable, and I want to back json from server. 
In Controller method addComment didn't enter.
How to fix this error?

Comment: Check these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335591/spring-mvc-json-406-not-acceptable , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908466/jquery-spring-mvc-requestbody-and-json-making-it-work-together , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473498/spring-mvc-406-not-acceptable-instead-of-json-response

Comment: These variants do not help

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem just "yesterday"

you must remove from the URL the `.htm` part

From:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcomment.html", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            headers="Content-Type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody MyComment AddComment(@RequestBody MyComment comm, 
                                          HttpServletRequest request, 
                                          HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

To:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcomment", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            headers="Content-Type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody MyComment AddComment(@RequestBody MyComment comm, 
                                          HttpServletRequest request, 
                                          HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

And

From:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8088/MyBlog.ua/addcomment.html",
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: dataaa,
   contentType: 'application/json',
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8088/MyBlog.ua/addcomment",
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: dataaa,
   contentType: 'application/json',
```

More information here: [Spring 4.0.x JSON/Ajax HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016367/3665178)