# Spring 4.0.x JSON/Ajax HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-json

I am working with Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE, Spring MVC through only **Java Config**

I have in my pom.xml the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

Where <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
```

I am using the Spring default configuration about JSON. In some `@Controller` I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getjsonperson", 
                method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Person getJSONPerson(){
    logger.info("getJSONPerson - getjsonperson");
    return PersonFactory.createPerson();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/getperson.json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person getPersonJSON(){
    logger.info("getPerson - getpersonJSON");
    return PersonFactory.createPerson();
}
```

And works fine. I can see in the browser the JSON value returned. Until here all is OK.

Now I want integrate Spring MVC + (JSON AJAX)

I have this tutorial how reference [Spring MVC: Ajax & JQuery](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/)

Ok, I have the following about JSON with AJAX (working through a select or combo box to load a second set or collection)

Note: The URL is static, even if I use only `/spring-utility/facturaajax/findallproductobycategoria.htm` the problem persists

```
$("#categoria").change(function(event){

    var json = {"id" : $(this).find("option:selected").val(), "nombre" : $(this).find("option:selected").text() };

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/facturaajax/findallproductobycategoria.htm" ,
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        type: "POST",

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },

        success: function(products) {
            alert("all fine!!!!");
        }

    });

    //event.preventDefault();
});
```

About the Controller I have the following to handle the ajax process

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findallproductobycategoria.htm", 
                method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Set<Producto> findAllProductoByCategoria(@RequestBody Categoria categoria){
    logger.info("findAllProductoByCategoria: {}", categoria.toString());
    return this.fakeMultipleRepository.findAllProductoByCategoria(categoria.getId());
}
```

Even if I use `headers="Accept=application/json"` or `headers="Content-Type=application/json"` the problem persists.

The POJOs are serializables

```
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5655804710111228325L;

public class Producto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6362590479124787529L;
```

**The problem**: When I change the value of my select html element, I always receive the **HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable** (see the two attached images)

[image: Error Message 01]

[image: Error Message 02]

BTW: The server side never is called.

I already have read other posts on SO. Practically all of them do mention about Jackson and are based on Spring **3.2.x**.

Even if I add the following, the problem persists

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

What is missing? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the audience.

The error was in the same URL.
It contains `.htm`

Therefore for all the developers be sure to remove it

From

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findallproductobycategoria.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Set<Producto> findAllProductoByCategoria(@RequestBody Categoria categoria){
    logger.info("findAllProductoByCategoria: {}", categoria.toString());
    return this.fakeMultipleRepository.findAllProductoByCategoria(categoria.getId());
}
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findallproductobycategoria", method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Set<Producto> findAllProductoByCategoria(@RequestBody Categoria categoria){
    logger.info("findAllProductoByCategoria: {}", categoria.toString());
    return this.fakeMultipleRepository.findAllProductoByCategoria(categoria.getId());
}
```

From:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/spring-utility/facturaajax/findallproductobycategoria.htm" ,
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/spring-utility/facturaajax/findallproductobycategoria" ,
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
```

Because I have

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    Map<String,MediaType> mediaTypes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    mediaTypes.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    mediaTypes.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    configurer.mediaTypes(mediaTypes);
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
}
```

Spring gives more preference about the URL *.extension* than the *header* content