# Spring json 406 status

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I've added jackson's jars to my project's lib directory `jackson-core-asl` and `jackson-mapper-asl`. I also have wirtten in my dispatcher-servlet.xml the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My controller is:

```
@Controller
public class SaleController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/sales/info", produces = "application/json", headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody Product getProductJson(@RequestParam String id) throws SQLException
    {
        ProductDAO mapping = new ProductDAOImpl();
        Product product = mapping.getProductById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        return product;
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to get this response in the browser I still recieve `406 HTTP status message` instead of JSON-response.

***NOTE***: ***Before You mark my post as duplicate, I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473498/spring-mvc-406-not-acceptable-instead-of-json-response), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235472/http-status-406-spring-mvc-4-0-jquery-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335591/spring-mvc-json-406-not-acceptable) but it doesn't work.***

Comment: Start by checking if you're sending with the `Content-Type: application/json` header and remove the `headers` attribute from the `@RequestMapping` and see if that works out.

Comment: You use an request parameter `id` which is not defined in the request mapping.

Comment: @Bart How to send with Content-Type: application/json?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv My bad. I see you only respond with JSON :-) Not sure which Spring MVC version you are using but you generally don't need to declare a message converter for Jackson. Spring will pick it up by itself. Also use Jackson 2+ whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring version 3.2.2 there is no need to register any custom message converter

so your configuration should be like this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

after that have these two dependencies in your POM file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

you can also try adding a application/json againt Accept header