# Spring 406 error while trying to return object in @ResponseBody

Tags: spring, serialization

my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
...
<jackson.mapper.version>1.9.13</jackson.mapper.version>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

rest-services-config.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.rest" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="text/plain"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

rest-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.rest" />



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.html</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/vendors/**" location="/resources/vendors/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/controls/**" location="/resources/controls/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Finally, here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserService {

@Autowired(required=true)
private UserDaoImpl dao;

@RequestMapping(value="/getCurrentUserCredentials/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserCredentials getCurrentUserCredentials() {
    HttpSession session = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession();
    try {
        return dao.getCurrentUserCredentials((Integer)session.getAttribute("userid"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

...and request which gives to me a 406error:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'user/getCurrentUserCredentials/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {console.log(data); self.currentUserCredentials(data);},
            error: function() {console.log('error');}
        });
```

---

Any suggestions about solving this? Help please.

Controller's method returns correct data (checked in debug) while this data can't be handled properly.

Comment: Try changing the MappingJacksonView in rest-services-config.xml to `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>`

Comment: unfortunately, "406" still

Comment: Is `getCurrentUserCredentials` throwing an exception or not?

Comment: Nono as I said - this method works perfectly;Obv.I have mistake somewhere in settings

Comment: have you tried using another rest client instead of jquery? Reason is that there is a similar question that points to the jquery being incorrect, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069903/spring-mvc-not-returning-json-content-error-406

Comment: in the browser open the network inspector, and check the request header `Accept` comparing it against the response `Content-Type`.

Comment: 406 also occurs when you don't have getters on the object you want to JSONify. I just ran into this issue and I thought I'd mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not meant to add a `@Produces` annotation here?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCurrentUserCredentials/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody UserCredentials getCurrentUserCredentials() {
    HttpSession session = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession();
    try {
        return dao.getCurrentUserCredentials((Integer)session.getAttribute("userid"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this matters, but the @ResponseBody annotation is also before the public keyword. My example is based on this [Spring reference code](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html):

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/error", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> handle(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("status", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"));
        map.put("reason", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));

        return map;
    }

}
```

There's also the option to have `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` for newer versions of Spring.

Comment: Hi, tried to prepend "@ResponseBody" before "public ..." but seems that it doesn't matter. Added "produce" parameter but still 406.

Comment: @Arti88, did you also try the produces part of the request mapping (i.e. `produces="application/json"`)?

Comment: Yea... still the same: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) http://localhost:8080/PR2/user/getCurrentUserCredentials/