# Why object to json conversion using spring MVC doesn't work in this case?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to execute this URL: http://localhost:8080/FitiProject/student and the response needs to be a json string containing the data of a `Student` object.

Here is my code:

```
package spring.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import model.Student;

@Controller
public class PruebaController {
    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public @ResponseBody Student getStudent(){
        return new Student(2, "h");
    }
}
```

This is Student.java

```
package model;

public class Student {
    private int edad;
    private String nombre;

    public Student(int edad, String nombre) {
        super();
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

When I do a GET request on the URL, I don't get a JSON response instead I get a 406 error code. How can I solve this?

I'm using Jackson 1.9 and Spring 4.1.

Comment: What exactly is your question??

Comment: <body>
      <h1>Estado HTTP 406 -</h1>
      <hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/>
      <p>
         <b>type</b>
         Informe de estado
      </p>
      <p>
         <b>mensaje</b>
      </p>
      <p>
         <b>descripción</b>
         <u>El recurso identificado por este requerimiento sólo es capaz de generar respuestas con características no aceptables con arreglo a las cabeceras "accept" de requerimiento.</u>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getStudent` method lacks the content type of the response, otherwise Spring won't know to which format convert the `Student`. This can be done by using `produces` attribute in `@RequestMapping`.

```
//"produces" will tell Spring to which format convert the data
//"method" will tell Spring which HTTP method should be handled for this URL
@RequestMapping(value="/student",
    produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Student getStudent(){
    return new Student(2, "h");
}
```

When executing a request to your URL, make sure that the client uses the following header: `Content-Type: application/json`

It's worth to mention that your project needs to have jackson libraries in order to work.

Comment: Error 406 :/ i cant get the json, just get a response with error.

Comment: Which version of Spring and Jackson are you using?

Comment: <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

Comment: <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
   <version>1.9.10</version>

Comment: For Spring 4, you should use Jackson 2.x as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27767809/1065197). Also, make sure your client accepts `application/json` as well.

Comment: Hablas español? estoy usando soapUI para probar.

Comment: Yes I do but in this site we communicate using English. If you want to communicate using Spanish, then you can post (or migrate maybe) your question to [StackOverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: When is it necessary to set the produces??

Comment: Does it not consider "application/json" as the content type by default ?

Comment: @codeMan please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28647129/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks. This is something I that learned newly today.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Jackson, you could try using the `ObjectMapper` class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println("Object in JSON:\n" + mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object));
```

Comment: Spring can handle this conversion for you

Comment: This was just an alternate solution which could be used to solve the problem. It wouldn't be my choice, but I had an example to hand so I thought I would share it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `@ResponseBody` annotation the response will be automatically converted to JSON. Make sure you include jackson mapper library in your class path.

If you are using Maven, you can add the jackson dependency as follows :

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RestController : `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController` to get automatic conversion of the responseBody into a `JSON Format`.